# My 'docker run' command uses 2 cpu cores by default. How to increase it?

Tags: image, docker, numbers, cpu

I’ve having i7 4c8h machine installed docker, just tried ubuntu 16.04 and found the /proc/cpuinfo shows the running container is using 2 logical calls.

My question is, how to change the cpu core number when running docker image?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running docker? Is this on Windows or Mac?

Comment: This probably is due to the Docker configuration in your compueter. I suspect you are using Windows or Mac. Go to the whale and see the settings

Comment: `docker run --cpuset-cpus="0" ...` http://stackoverflow.com/a/25999490/6085135